# Type definition for function in a namespace that returns this

Tags: typescript

I try to write the type definition for a function in a namespace (`L.DomEvent.on(e)`) that returns `this`. The JavaScript source code is like

```
L.DomEvent = {
    // @function on(el: HTMLElement, eventMap: Object, context?: Object): this
    on: function(e) {
        // do stuff
        return this;
    }
}
```

See the [detail source code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/dom/DomEvent.js#L23).

I first write the definition as following

```
declare namespace L {
    export namespace DomEvent {
        export function on(el: HTMLScriptElement): this;
    }
}
```

But the compiler throws an error with the message

```
error TS2526: A 'this' type is available only in a non-static member of a class or interface.
```

Although I can change the output from `this` to `any` (it works), I wonder if there is better solution to define the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code in github your declaration should look like this:

```
declare namespace L {
    export namespace DomEvent {
        export function on(el: HTMLElement, types: string, fn: Function, context?: any): typeof DomEvent;
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20namespace%20L%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20namespace%20DomEvent%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20export%20function%20on(el%3A%20HTMLElement%2C%20types%3A%20string%2C%20fn%3A%20Function%2C%20context%3F%3A%20any)%3A%20typeof%20DomEvent%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D))

You only return `this` as a type when you need it as [polymorphic this types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types), but in this case the `this` that is returned is that `DomEvent` namespace, so we return `typeof DomEvent`.